# Python, Quandl: ImportError: cannot import name get

Tags: python, quandl

I am new to Python and trying to import data from `Quandl` for some analysis.
Unfortunately, when I try to get data from `Quandl` using `quandl.get` as below:

```
import quandl

data = quandl.get("FRED/GDP")
```

It shows the following error says that

> ImportError: cannot import name get.

Can someone help me please. Thank you.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Jan/qdata.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jan')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-37b75ee200ca>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Jan/qdata.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jan')

  File "C:\Users\Jan\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Jan\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Jan/qdata.py", line 7, in <module>
    import quandl

  File "quandl.py", line 8, in <module>

ImportError: cannot import name get
```

Comment: Do you also have a file in the directory named quandl.py?

Comment: @Octo Clearly he does :) `File "quandl.py", line 8, in <module>`

Comment: Thats what I thought. Just confirming. You cant have a quandl.py in your project directory.

Comment: Thanks Octo I dont have a quandl.py in my project directory.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. It was working last week! Did you find out anything?

Comment: Remove the file named `quandl.py`; or rename it.

Answer (score 0):

I had named the file I was working on `quandl.py` When I changed the name of the file and deleted `quandl.py` it started working again.